# TypeError: db.startsWith is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I want a leaderboard of users on my server but here is error in db.startsWith :((
maybe in a new version quick.db ?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const db = require("quick.db");


module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  let money = db.startsWith(`money_${message.guild.id}`, { sort: '.data'})
  let content = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < money.length; i++) {
    let user = bot.users.get(money[i].ID.split('_')[2]).username

    content += `${i+1}. ${user} ~ ${money[i].data} монет\n`
  }

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} - Leaderboard`, message.guild.iconURL)
  .setDescription(content)
  .setColor("RANDOM")

  message.channel.send(embed)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

By exploring the `quick.db` package with unpkg.com, I have found that the `startsWith` function - along with some other deprecated functions - was removed in version `7.0.0-b22`. This is supported by information in an answer from [support.glitch.com](https://support.glitch.com/t/discord-bot-with-quick-db-db-startswith-is-not-a-function/9120):

> When I do a `console.log(db)` after `require`ing that package, I get a version of `7.0.0b22` and indeed it seems like that version doesn’t export a startsWith function, while `7.0.0b21` does. If you remove the “^” from the beginning of the `quick.db` version specifier I think your current code will work, but it seems as though that function is being deprecated and I’d probably find a different solution to *that* instead.

and [the official documentation](https://quickdb.js.org/docs.html).

Looking at said documentation, I can find no workaround other than to get all entries in the database via the `all` method and manually filter the returned array to the entries that you want. As the documentation does not tell the structure of the array returned from `all`, I cannot help you with that—perhaps some experimentation of your own may reveal the structure to you?